# Inverse of a bijection is a bijection

Tags: functions

Please help me with the following question.

Prove:

$f:S \to T$ is bijection $\Rightarrow$ $f^{^{-1}} : T\to S$ is bijection.

Comment: This is said to be a probability question, but it looks like a linear algebra question and is tagged as a geometry question...

Comment: @EuYu:Sorry.
Thanks for your hint.

Comment: Do you know the definition of bijection?

Comment: @Karolis Juodele:yes. but I do not know about this prove.

Comment: It looks like a set theoretic question to me. There are no tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already know the theorem that a function is bijective if and only if it has an inverse then this follows readily by noting that $(f^{-1})^{-1} = f$ so that $f^{-1}$ has an inverse and is hence bijective.

Otherwise, suppose $f$ is a bijection and let $f^{-1}$ denote its inverse. Then $f^{-1}$ is onto since for any $x\in S$ we have
$$f^{-1}\left(f(x)\right) = x$$
therefore $x$ is in the image of $f^{-1}$ under $f(x)$.

To show that $f^{-1}$ is injective, suppose that we have $f^{-1}(x) = f^{-1}(y)$. Then we have
$$x=f\left(f^{-1}(x)\right) = f\left(f^{-1}(y)\right)=y$$
so that $f^{-1}$ is injective. Hence $f^{-1}$ is bijective.

Notice that nowhere did we explicitly use the fact that $f$ is a bijection. The assumption is hidden in the fact that only bijective functions have inverses in the first place.

Comment: +++Thanks very much for your answer:)